# Get commands by two criteria

Tags: powershell

How can we execute Get-Command command to get result by two criteria? Let's say it this way: I want in one execution to get list of commands that starts with **Add** or **Get**

Documentation of `Get-Command` command states that `-Verb` attribute accepts multiple verbs or verb pattern, but I don't get it how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it worked like this:

```
Get-Command -verb Get,Add
```